# How to to load internal json instead of an external JSON-file with $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use a snippet which loads strings from an external json-file. Everything works fine, but when I start the function locally, I get a 'cross origin'-issue. Therefore, I want to put the strings directly in my JS, but it do not work.

**Origin JS**

```
$scope.loadAutosuggest = function(query) {
    return $http.get('data.json');
};
```

**data.json**

```
[
    "In Progress: Yes",
    "In Progress: No"
]
```

I´ve tried to do this like here (but it do not work)

```
$scope.loadAutosuggest = [
 "In Progress: Yes",
 "In Progress: No"          
];
```

Do you have any tips for me? Thank you

Comment: are you just running the function locally as in just run the .html file that you have got?

Comment: Try start server on localhost. You can use `grunt` https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect `SimpleHTTPServer` https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html or any you have in touch

Comment: You missed an equals sign before your array. Also make sure that $scope is already defined

Comment: Which server are u using? Are you at least running the app on a server when u say 'running it locally'? You are doing a `$http.get()` obviously needs resources on server..

Comment: @dops: that was a copy/paste error...I get an "fn is not a function"-issue

Comment: I want to send this bundle to a customer and he should be able to run it without installing a server. So I´ve decided to bind it internal in the js

Comment: in that case, you dont need to do a http.get(), you cannot! it is sort of hard coding the values, you would have to write an angular service which returns data(that you have in json) and inject it as a module/service in your controller. Dont use http.get() if it's not gonna run on the server.

Comment: your edited version should work.. wonder why it isn't!!

Comment: @Suhansu: And that was the question, how :-)

Comment: I use a snippet from there http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos to load the autosuggest-tags

Comment: hey, can you show the code on your html page? I hope you are not trying to pass any parameter from the page to loadAutoSuggest function, coz u dont need to... it should be just `ng-repeat="autoSuggest in loadAutoSuggest"` not `ng-repeat="autoSuggest in loadAutoSuggest(someParam)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81116/discussion-between-sudhansu-choudhary-and-mm1975).

Comment: Thank you Sudhansu! I use the snippet from just95 and it works great. Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that `$scope.loadAutosuggest` is expected to be a function.

```
$scope.loadAutosuggest = function() {
  return [
    "In Progress: Yes",
    "In Progress: No"          
  ];
};
```